# Authenticate (or validate JWT) only at certain routes in Spring Gateway

Tags: java, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

My Setup looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the Gateway gets all requests to route `/api` from an Angular.

The Angular app authenticates the User with MSAL Lib to an Azure B2C, gets a token and makes requests to the respective service with that JWT.

What I added to the Gateway ([according to this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2)) is a "Resource Server" with its configuration in the gateways `application.yaml` like:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: ${CIAM_B2C_JWK_SET_URI}
          issuer-uri: ${CIAM_B2C_ISSUER_URI}
          audiences: ${CIAM_B2C_AUDIENCES}
```

Now every request that passes the gateway needs a valid JWT. This is fine for "Secure Service One" and "Secure Service Two".

Furthermore, all routes are also configured in `application.yaml` like:

```
      routes:
        # secure service one
        - id: secure-service-one
          uri: http://localhost:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/secure-service-one/public/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=3
```

My issue is, that "Public Service" is also secured where I don't want a JWT validation.

I know I could probably add a `SecurityConfiguration` and say that the route is not secured,  but I think there should be a way where I could do it with a `filter` like:

```
      routes:
        # secure service one
        - id: secure-service-one
          uri: http://localhost:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/secure-service-one/public/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=3
            - AuthenticationFilter
```

so I have the settings for every route at one place.

Appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring Security team latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), we should only use "confidential" OAuth2 clients. This excludes single page (Angular, React, Vue, Flutter web,...) and mobile applications, but makes the gateway a good candidate for it. **The requests from frontend (Angular in your case) to the gateway should be authorized with session cookies**, not `Bearer` tokens in `Authorization` header. This is frequently referred to as "BFF pattern" and I wrote [a tutorial for it](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

The "services" on your drowning are what actually serve resources. It know about this resources internal and business rules. Access control (who can access and what he can do with it) is part of this business and is best placed on resource servers. If we take the sample of a "forum" application, a "post" can be edited by any user having the "moderator" *authority* or the user having the "author" *relation* with this post. A gateway should not know about relations between resources and such access control rule can be easily unit tested only on the "post service" which knows about posts relations and should then be a resource server implementing (and unit-testing) this access control.

The only valid cases for an access token to come with a request to the gateway is when "services" talk to each other through this gateway or if a "server from the outside" needs to query your API. But this doesn't require the gateway to be configured as resource server nor implement access control, as long as the services behind it are resource servers with access control.

In short, put access control on the gateway only for its own resources (things like actuator endpoints) and define routes:

- with `oauth2Login` and `TokenRelay` filter for frontends (like your Angular app) needing a user session
- without session nor `TokenRelay` for inter-service communication and gateway own resources.

This will probably require to define:

- two different `Security(Web)FilterChain` beans: one as OAuth2 client with sessions and login, and another as resource server without session
- if inter-service communication goes through the gateway, two different routes to each resource server (with and without the `TokenRelay` filter)

Comment: thx for the answer @ch4mp, it seams like I need TokenRelay, but the gateway shall not work as a client which needs to redirect the user to the login, this is handled by the angular app itself. Would this still be possible with TokenRelay? So the requests are already coming with a valid JWT and only on defined routes by `TokenRelay` the JWT is validated?!

Comment: `TokenRelay` filter can work only if tokens are in session, which require the gateway to be configured as an OAuth2 client (with `oauth2Login` if you want this tokens to be delivered for the user using `authorization_code` flow).

Comment: And read my answer again: **Angular should not fetch tokens from the authorization server** (actually, it should not even see the tokens). Also, **the gateway should check the access tokens only for requests to its own protected resources** (like actuator endpoints), not for requests to resource served by services behind it.